# Install from a USB but while in Linux

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I'm trying to install from a USB with ubuntu but the laptop is pretty old and for some reason the setup wouldn't find the USB in the boot priority menu.

How do you start the installation from within linux using the USB bootable stick?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your laptop if it can boot from USB? Go to this [link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/testing-your-system-for-usb-boot-compatibility/) to test if your laptop can boot from USB.